# Python Having Problems Getting Turtle's Canvas Up

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I just got a book on kids coding in Python for Christmas.  I was really excited to use it and downloaded the app immediately.  The book said to use this code to import Turtle:

```
>>> import turtle
```

Then it said this to create a canvas:

```
>>> t = turtle.Pen ()
```

This error message appeared.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    t = turtle.Pen ()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Pen'
```

What does this mean?  How do I get Turtle's canvas up?

Comment: [pen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pen) is lowercase

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: If any answer solved your problem it is nice to vote them up (you need some reputation for that ) and mark the most helpful as "answer" to your question. In case you stil have problems, comment your qestions below the answer.

Comment: @gogaz, both `Pen()` and `pen()` exist in turtle but have different meanings.  The lower case `pen()` is **not** what the OP wants in this case.

Comment: Hi!  Thank you so much for your help!  I have solved the problem by entering the first code into the Apple Terminal.  Thank you so much for helping me get Python working!  I am so excited to use Turtle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
# load the turtle module
import turtle

# the imported module turtle has a Turtle() that moves around 
# give your turtle a name so you can refer to turtle.Turtle() by the shorter name
# tim (i.e.)
tim = turtle.Turtle()

# Move tim
tim.forward(50)

# end turtling
turtle.done()
```

`tim` ( the `turtle.Turtle()` ) can do many more things, this page holds informations about the turtle, its methods and some exampels:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

Comment: This still doesn't work.  The error message this time is:                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    turtle.turtle.pen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'pen'                                              Is there another way?

Comment: @StarlightJenna use `turtle.Turtle().pen()`  - or give the turtle a shorter name: `tim = turtle.Turtle()` -then you can use `tim.pen()`

Comment: `turtle.Pen()` is an alias for `turtle.Turtle()` so this doesn't explain why the OP had a problem, nor necessarily fix it.  Calling the `pen()` method is completely unrelated to the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

After import turtle, you want to enter a variable name which is to call the turtle via that variable.

Syntax:

```
import turtle
your_variable_name = turtle.Turtle()
```

After that, you want to accessed into the turtle.

```
your_variable_name.pencolor('blue')
```

Comment: turtle.Pen() is an alias for turtle.Turtle() so this doesn't explain why the OP had a problem, nor necessarily fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is in fact *correct*, despite the comments and other answers:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Pen ()
```

for example:

```
> python3
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Pen()
>>> t
<turtle.Turtle object at 0x101ca4ac8>
>>> ^D
```

The question is, why didn't it work for *you*?  My initial guess is you've created a file called `turtle.py` on your working directory -- if so rename it or delete it and try again.  Otherwise Python finds your turtle.py file instead of the Python library turtle.py file when you `import turtle`.  If that's not the case:

My second guess is you're using a limited Python environment that implements it's own subset of turtle.  For example online coding with turtle on https://trinket.io/turtle uses such a subset where `Pen()` won't work but `Turtle()` (it's alias in the standard turtle library) works just fine. So try `Turtle()` instead of `Pen()`